# Python Ordered Tuple list ranked by absolute value

Tags: python, list, pandas, tuples

I am trying to create an ordered tuple list based on rows of information:

```
team   stat1 explain1     stat2 explain2     stat3  explain3
green  +10   inc due to.. -8    dec due to.. +2     inc due to..
blue   -6    dec due to.. +5    inc due to.. +8     inc due to..
red    +5    inc due to.. +10   inc due to.. -2     dec due to..
```

I would like to create an ordered tuple list per team(by absolute value), so 'team' 'blue' would look like:

```
tuple list based on above order:       Abs value ordered tuple list:
-6: dec due to..                        8: incr due to..
 5: inc due to..                       -6: decr due to..     
 8: inc due to..                        5: incr due to..
```

Comment: This should be done for *all stats together*, or for one of the stats?

Comment: Hi Martijn, thank you.  This is one block for a larger program.  I am trying to write commentary per team in descending order with regard to which stat had the largest role in the period over period move.  The explain is pretty easy to program, but the overall picture seems challenging.  There are 5 stats in total, 20 teams and I need to write commentary per team that explains all 5 changes.  The teams are ranked in order by the total stats sum.

Comment: Right, so why not produce output *for each single row* after transposing?

Comment: So produce a separate dataframe with 'stat' and 'explain' columns, sort that dataframe by absolute value, and produce a report from that.  You can keep the team info in that and use grouping.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you are saying, yes that could work!  Last question, once I do that, how would i apply the negative values back to the list once it is in absolute value order?  Martijn, thanks again for you additional commentary!

Comment: You add an *extra* column to sort on, containing absolute values. You retain the original stats.

Comment: Ok great!  Thank you Martijn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Transpose* your dataframe to form three rows per team, each row consisting of the team name, the stat change value, and the explanation for that single stat. Add in a new column with absolute values so you can easily sort on that:

```
transposed_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'team': np.repeat(df.transpose().iloc[0].values, 3),
    'stat': pd.concat((
        df.transpose().iloc[1::2, i]
        for i in range(3)), ignore_index=True),
    'explain': pd.concat((
        df.transpose().iloc[2::2, i]
        for i in range(3)), ignore_index=True),
    'abs_stat': pd.concat((
        df.transpose().iloc[1::2, i]
        for i in range(3)), ignore_index=True).abs(),
}, columns=['team', 'stat', 'explain', 'abs_stat'])
```

Now it is trivial to produce your sorted output:

```
transposed_df.sort_values(by=['team', 'abs_stat'], ascending=False).drop('abs_stat', axis=1)
```

This produces:

```
    team stat       explain
7    red   10  inc due to..
6    red    5  inc due to..
8    red   -2  dec due to..
0  green   10  inc due to..
1  green   -8  dec due to..
2  green    2  inc due to..
5   blue    8  inc due to..
3   blue   -6  dec due to..
4   blue    5  inc due to..
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I had thought of that as well, but I am doing this by row and not column.  I could create an absolute value column for each stat and then create the list based on those absolute numbers, but i would need the final list to represent the negative values in the absolute order list

Comment: @John: ah, sorry, I was trying to figure out what you were sorting on, indeed. You want the 3 stats in each row to be sorted by absolute value then?